# How to mock element in an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I have a very simple directive :

```
angular.module('myModule',[]).directive('myInputAutofocus', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {            
      element.focus();
    }
  };
});
```

How can I test this one ? I can't find a way to mock *element*

**EDIT** : I've made a fiddle to explain my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/8qBbR/

Comment: Have you tested your directive with a browser ?

Comment: Yes and it works. But my problem is the same with whichever jquery plugin you want to use.

Comment: I was saying this because `element.focus()` should be `element[0].focus()`.

Comment: Focus method exist on Jquery Element : http://api.jquery.com/focus/ and I have jquery in my application, so it's not the angular-jquery-lite version of the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look on how [angular ui test their jQuery Passthru directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/jq/test/jqSpec.js) :

```
  spyOn(jQuery.fn, 'foo');

  compile('<div ui-jq="foo"></div>')(scope);

  timeout.flush();
  expect(jQuery.fn.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use $compile to provide raw HTML for testing your directive.

Your test setup would look like this:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
var element = $compile('<div my-input-auto-focus=""></div>')(scope);
```

You could also "prep" the element using `angular.element('<div...');`

Comment: when I do : **var element = angular.element('<div my-input-auto-focus=""></div>');var element2 = $compile(element)(scope);** then element and element2 are totally different and my mocked focus method on element is not on element2